# Model::query() doesn't return Model-name in results

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, cakephp-2.3, postgresql-8.4

When I execute some query with a `$this->query`, CakePHP return this:

**Model**:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Authorization extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = 'name';
    public $useTable = 'auth';
    public $actsAs = array();
```

**SQL in Model**:

```
public function getNotUsed($initialDate, $finalDate)
{

  $sql = "SELECT auth_num ,
               auth_code ,
               amount AS verisign_amount ,
               print_amount ,
               card_name ,
               a.table_num AS table_num ,
               a.add_date AS date ,
               'Tb:'|| table_num || ' - ' || auth_code || ' - $' || print_amount AS code_print_amount
          FROM auth a
          WHERE trxtype = 'S'
            AND gift_card = 'N'
            AND used = 'N'
            AND a.add_date BETWEEN '$initialDate' AND '$finalDate'
            AND pnref NOT IN
              (SELECT origid
               FROM auth a
               WHERE add_date BETWEEN '$initialDate' AND '$finalDate'
                 AND trxtype = 'V')
          ORDER BY add_date";

  return $this->query($sql);

}
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [auth_num] => 536825
                    [auth_code] => 0000000
                    [verisign_amount] => 0.50
                    [print_amount] => 0.50
                    [card_name] => TEST
                    [table_num] => 37
                    [date] => 02/20/2013 14:56:35
                    [code_print_amount] => Tb:37 - 198198 - $0.50
                )

        )

)
```

I want this (when search more than 1 row):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['Authorization'] => Array
                (
                    [auth_num] => 536825
                    [auth_code] => 0000000
                    [verisign_amount] => 0.50
                    [print_amount] => 0.50
                    [card_name] => TEST
                    [table_num] => 37
                    [date] => 02/20/2013 14:56:35
                    [code_print_amount] => Tb:37 - 198198 - $0.50
                )

        )

)
```

Or this (when search more 1 row - limit 1):

```
Array
(
       ['Authorization'] => Array
           (
               [auth_num] => 536825
               [auth_code] => 0000000
               [verisign_amount] => 0.50
               [print_amount] => 0.50
               [card_name] => TEST
               [table_num] => 37
               [date] => 02/20/2013 14:56:35
               [code_print_amount] => Tb:37 - 198198 - $0.50
         )
)
```

**How can I execute this query and get just a first array key (with all fields). In this case, the 2nd array key [0]. Or just a `[0] => ['Authorization'] => array()`.**

---

I'm using:

- CakePHP 2.3.0
- PHP 5.3.8
- Apache 2.2
- Postgres 8.4

Comment: @PatrickMeciel, do you need the first record or the first field (e.g. `auth_num` only)?

Comment: @SamDelaney I need first record in this case: all fields

Comment: I think we're getting there @PatrickMaciel, I think it has something to do with aliasing but so that we're sure, do you think you could post what you want the array to look like? I'm sure we'll be able to reverse engineer the correct SQL syntax from that!

Comment: @SamDelaney I updated my question, see above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Only use RAW SQL if *really* nescessary

First of all, try to avoid using RAW SQL queries unless there's really no other option. Also, when using RAW SQL, keep in mind that **you will have to sanitize your queries yourself to prevent SQL injection**. Since you're dealing with payment information, please double check that you're escaping `$initialDate` and `$finalDate`, because I don't see any security measures in your code.

## Formatting the results

To get the results the way you want, you'll have to use aliases for your fields in a 'special' format;

```
SELECT
    myfield      AS "Mymodel__somefield", 
    myotherfield AS "Mymodel__someotherfield"

FROM .....
```

**note** there should be *two* underscores between `Mymodel` and `fieldname`

Should return;

```
array (
    0 => array(
        'Mymodel' => array (
            'somefield' => 'foo',
            'otherfield' => 'bar',
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I understand the risc, but my problem to do this querys, or, like that, is: subqueries / case when. In  this project, I'm migrate the old system in pure php 4 for CakePHP, and have a lot subqueries / case when. Folowing documentation of CakePHP I need write a lot code to write simple subquery.

Comment: @PatrickMaciel at least read the chapter on [Data Sanitization](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html), also [`Model::query()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L3061) *does* support query parameters, e.g. `Model::query("SELECT a FROM mytable WHERE id = ?", array(12345));`

Answer (score 1):

So taking @thaJeztah's advice, your query needs to be changed to something like following:

```
$sql = "SELECT `Authentication`.`auth_num`,
               `Authentication`.`auth_code`,
               `Authentication`.`amount` AS `Authentication`.`verisign_amount`,
               `Authentication`.`print_amount`,
               `Authentication`.`card_name`,
               `Authentication`.`table_num`,
               `Authentication`.`add_date` AS `Authentication`.`date`,
               'Tb:'|| `Authentication`.`table_num` || ' - ' || `Authentication`.`auth_code` || ' - $' || `Authentication`.`print_amount` AS `Authentication`.`code_print_amount`
          FROM `auth` as `Authentication`
          WHERE `Authentication`.`trxtype` = 'S'
            AND `Authentication`.`gift_card` = 'N'
            AND `Authentication`.`used` = 'N'
            AND `Authentication`.`add_date` BETWEEN '?' AND '?'
            AND `Authentication`.`pnref` NOT IN
              (SELECT o`Authentication`.`rigid`
               FROM `auth` as `Authentication`
               WHERE `Authentication`.`add_date` BETWEEN '?' AND '?'
                 AND `Authentication`.`trxtype` = 'V')
          ORDER BY `Authentication`.`add_date`";
```

I actually took a bit of a chance in guessing which tables stuff came from. It is really important to namespace your fields so you don't leave the database guessing where the fields come from.

Also to echo @theJeztah's answer, try and avoid writing SQL yourself. If you have sub-queries, then try to break them into multiple `$this->model->find(...)`. Its not as quick but its probably far safer.

Comment: Thank you Sam. Yes, you're right. I have not converted this query to CakePHP (ORM), because when I do that, the performance drops a lot, and as I am migrating the system, my client does not like it, based on the system it was developed in pure PHP 4. Anyway, I'll do more tests and while using query parameters as you said above. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code might be:

```
$this->query('select * etc');
```

Show us more code, if this doesn't work.

Comment: I add the query in my question.

Comment: Check it @PatrickMaciel http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html your query is right. but i think your model might be extends the wrong class.

Comment: Extends wrong class? I not understand what you say (see the question, I updated it)